# AutoCompleteBox Strange Popup Position Behavior

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I'm adding auto complete to a new app using AutoCompleteBox. I noticed some strange behavior of the popup positon. Sometimes (about 70%) it'll popup slightly higher and blocks half of the textbox, while sometimes it just works fine. There're two AutoCompleteBoxes in my app and both of them have this behavior. Have anyone experienced this before?

I'm using the November 2011 toolkit.

[image]